# How can I use weight in actions condition for shopping cart price rule?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to use a rule involving shipping weight. I have set Use for Promo Rule Conditions to yes. It does not show up. Any other attribute works fine.

After some research I found this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172746/magento-cant-use-attribute-weight-in-actions-condition-for-shopping-cart-price

"I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but it seams like you cannot use the weight attribute for the rule conditions and actions.
When checking if an attribute is valid for rules this method is called

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::isAllowedForRuleCondition

public function isAllowedForRuleCondition()
{
$allowedInputTypes = array('text', 'multiselect', 'textarea', 'date',     'datetime', 'select', 'boolean', 'price');
return $this->getIsVisible() && in_array($this->getFrontendInput(), $allowedInputTypes);
}
```

This seams reasonable. Now the strange part.
The weight attribute has the frontend input weight.
You can see this by running this query on the db.

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'weight'.
```

Changing the frontend_input to text makes the attribute available in promo rules. But I can't tell you if this is a good idea or not."

Has anyone tried this? I hate modifying any core files. The strange part is others that have text field selected, work just fine. It is just weight I have the issue with.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the front end properties of weight it will show as text. That is wrong. It is actually weight. If you take this code-

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::isAllowedForRuleCondition

public function isAllowedForRuleCondition()
{
$allowedInputTypes = array('text', 'multiselect', 'textarea', 'date',     'datetime', 'select', 'boolean', 'price');
return $this->getIsVisible() && in_array($this->getFrontendInput(), $allowedInputTypes);
}
```

And add weight so it looks like this-

```
   $allowedInputTypes = array('text', 'multiselect', 'textarea', 'date','datetime', 'select', 'boolean', 'price','weight');
```

If you add 'weight' to the end it will now show up properly.